# java 8 streams - Add two items in a list into a different item in the same list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list with a custom class. I want to take the subSectionRank and the featureRank into the field rankingValue

I can do this with a loop but would like to be more efficient and use streams as the list is 400+

Here is the list

[image]

Here is the loop

```
 public List<BaseFeatures> addFeatureRanking(List<BaseFeatures> baseFeatures){

    for (int i = 0; i < baseFeatures.size(); i++) {
        Integer subSectionRank =  baseFeatures.get(i).getSubSectionRank();
        Double featureRank = baseFeatures.get(i).getFeatureRank();
        int ranking = (int) ((int)subSectionRank + featureRank);
        baseFeatures.get(i).setRankingValue(ranking);
    }

    return baseFeatures;
}
```

Here is what i am trying.

```
    List<Map.Entry<Double, Integer>> reducedAList = new ArrayList<>(baseFeatures.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BaseFeatures::getFeatureRank, Collectors.summingInt(BaseFeatures::getSubSectionRank)))
            .entrySet());
```

I just dont know if i am on the right track or even remotely close. How can i use java 8 streams to accomplish what i am asking? Any heklp is much appreciated as java 8 streams is not my strong point.

Comment: How do you want to combine two fields (subSectionRank and featureRank) into one (rankingValue)?

Comment: How do you want to combine two fields (subSectionRank and featureRank) into one (rankingValue)?   Yes each index has a rankinValue that i want to set

Comment: `baseFeatures.forEach(b -> b.setRankingValue(b.getFeatureRank()+ b.getFeatureRank()));`

Comment: i figured that out after i asked lol but anyways this works. So, thank you

Comment: put that into an answer and i will accept?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like all you want to do is the following:

where

- `BaseFeature` is the class with the getters and setters
- `baseFeatures` is the list of those classes.

```
for (BaseFeature bf : baseFeatures) {
    bf.setRankingValue(bf.getFeatureRank() + bf.getsubSectionRank());
}
```

I'm not sure of the types so you may need to do some casting.